# Lines containing the same number of characters behaving differently depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

using bootstrap 4 I'm devloping a website and I noticed that different strings of character containing the same number of characters behave differently from one another and I'd like to know why and if there is a fix for that.
A picture is worth a thousand words so here are the screenshots:
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-check-date">
        <input class="" value="" id="defaultCheck1" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        <b class="form-date-english">Sat. December 1</b>
        <p class="form-date-french">Sam. 1 Décembre</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-check-date">
        <input class="" value="" id="defaultCheck1" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        <b class="form-date-english">Sun. December 2</b>
        <p class="form-date-french">Dim. 2 Décembre</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-check-date">
        <input class="" value="" id="defaultCheck1" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        <b class="form-date-english">Mon. December 3</b>
        <p class="form-date-french">Lun. 3 Décembre</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-check-date">
        <input class="" value="" id="defaultCheck1" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        <b class="form-date-english">Tue. December 4</b>
        <p class="form-date-french">Mar. 4 Décembre</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-check-date">
        <input class="" value="" id="defaultCheck1" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        <b class="form-date-english">Wed. December 5</b>
        <p class="form-date-french">Mer. 5 Décembre</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-check-date">
        <input class="" value="" id="defaultCheck1" type="checkbox">
        <br>
        <b class="form-date-english">Thu. December 6</b>
        <p class="form-date-french">Jeu. 6 Décembre</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here the custom CSS classes:

```
.form-check-date{
text-align: center;
}
.form-date-english{
color: #676767;
font-size: 0.8em;
}
.form-date-french{
color: black;
font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please include the images inline.

Comment: Can you provide an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is because the M and the W are a bit wider than the other letters.

One option would be to just accept it – this is how text flows naturally and it doesn’t look broken.

Or, if you would really like the various days to wrap at the same time, you could try replacing the space between the day number and the month with a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`), or enclose them in a `span` with `white-space: no-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about the code, but simply the fact that characters have different widths.